# Wrong number of cpu cores in /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: cpu, cpuinfo

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have an Intel i9 9980xe CPU, which has 18 cores and 2 threads per core. But it shows that the CPU has only 15 cores in /proc/cpuinfo as well as in htop. Why?

Here is the part of content in cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 85
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980XE CPU @ 3.00GHz
stepping        : 4
microcode       : 0x200005e
cpu MHz         : 1200.143
cache size      : 25344 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 15
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 15
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 22
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_pkg_req md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds
bogomips        : 6000.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

The output of lscpu:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              15
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-14
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  15
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980XE CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             1200.425
CPU max MHz:         4500.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            6000.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            25344K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-14
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_pkg_req md_clear flush_l1d
```

Comment: Please update you question with the output of /porc/cpuinfo ..

Comment: updated in question. Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `lscpu` ?

Comment: Updated in question. Thx

Comment: Ill say it first then: probably a bug. either in the hardware reporting to linux or the linux kernel.

Comment: Just curious. What is the output of `systemd-detect-virt`?

Comment: The output of `systemd-detect-virt` is none

Comment: Can you also check `dmesg | grep -i smpboot` and `grep CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/config-$(uname -r)` outputs?

Comment: The output of `dmesg | grep -i smpboot` is:
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 15 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.044048] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980XE CPU @ 3.00GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x55, stepping: 0x4)
[    0.177396] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[    0.177396] smpboot: Total of 15 processors activated (90000.00 BogoMIPS)
And the output of `grep CONFIG_NR_CPUS /boot/config-$(uname -r)` is 8192

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a hardware problem? Can you test with another OS (like Windows)? Was this always like this (since the installation of the server)?

Comment: The kernel is 4.15.0-54-generic. And I'm not sure if this problem still exists in other OSs, but it shows that 18 cores in bios setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem. Just because misconfigured the bios.

My colleague installed Win10 on this computer before. However, in the process of installation, he met a "blue screen" error and fixed it through disabling 3 cores of this CPU in bios.  That’s the reason why there are only 15 cores shown in my Ubuntu OS.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you please explain how you solved it?  What BIOS config was it?

Comment: If you put an answer to your own question, you should explain the solution in detail. At least you should respect the people who had spent time to help you! :(

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will restart the OS after finishing my program and update this answer.

Comment: @dachougui please edit this answer to explain how you actually solved it.  I see that you are a new user, so it's important to learn that this site is for providing questions and answers, and if you solve  your own problem it's important that you write up how you solved it so others may benefit.  Questions are intended to be of wider usefulness to others than just your own situation.

Comment: Thx for your advice. I've updated my answer. I apologize for my earlier behavior.